# Difference in the meaning of the various phrasal verbs of tear

Tags: word-meaning

What is the difference in the meaning of the following sentences:

> > "I found the map, but one of its corners had been **torn away.**"
> >
> > "I found the map, but one of its corners had been **torn off.**"
> >
> > "I found the map, but one of its corners had been **torn down.**"
> >
> > "I found the map, but one of its corners had been **torn apart.**"

Does **"torn away"** means that the corner of the page was torn apart/down and then it was lost?

I just searched few articles where different prepositions related to tearing of page were mentioned, which I covered in the above questions. I also searched these phrasal verbs in the standard dictionaries such as Oxford and Cambridge, but I didn't find any specific example.

Comment: I updated my question with my research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last two examples would not be used to describe the corner of a page.

The first two, *torn off*, and *torn away*, are more or less synonymous. Essentially, they mean the same thing - to be literally torn/ripped from something.

*Torn down* refers to something being demolished, like a structure for example.

e.g. *The building was torn down.*

*Torn apart* refers to two or more things being torn from each other. It's often used figuratively to mean being separated from someone you care about.

e.g. *When she left for Australia, he felt as if they had been torn apart.*

It can also be used literally

e.g. *The pages of the book had been torn apart.*

Answer (score 2):

1. **Torn away** - mostly means that something/someone was extracted/removed from something/somewhere *(isn't a part anymore)*. In some cases it carries the same meaning as "*tear off*".

   - The people were torn away from their homes during the war.
   - They had torn away his identity.
2. **Torn off** - mostly means that something was separate or caused to be separate abruptly/ripped.

   - The man's head was torn off and lay separate from the body.
   - A piece of the label was torn off.
3. **Torn down** - mostly means that something was dismantled, broken down, disintegrated, or disassembling entirely. *(mostly about buildings or structures)*

   - The old building was torn down because it was posing a threat to its residents.
   - The engine of the car was torn down and later reassembled.
4. **Torn apart** - mostly means that something was completely destroyed by tearing it into pieces or damaged *(also massively or a lot)*. Also idiomatic when speaking about relationship and feelings.

   - The place was torn apart - somebody had been looking for something.
   - One of the pipes was torn apart as if a bomb exploded inside.